# How can I test that a webpage returns 404/500 using PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm new at PhantomJS and Javascript and I'm working on a script that test the loading time and I would like for it to detect whether there was a error 404/500 encountered while testing it and display and message in the console.log. The code goes like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), t, address;
t = Date.now();

var testArray =
['someURL'];

function loadTest(testURL)
{
address = testURL;
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL to load the address' + address);
return;
    }

});
}

for(var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++)
{
loadTest(testArray[i]);
t = Date.now() - t;
console.log('Testing ' + testArray[i]);
console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec\n');
}
phantom.exit();
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the `onResourceReceived` callback to the page object, you should be able to get what you need from there. ([API docs...](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-webpage-onResourceReceived))

This is a bit of a contrived example, and it is going to give back the status code for every resource retrieved as part of the request, but the first one will be the page itself (i.e., as opposed to supporting JS or CSS etc.):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceReceived = function(res) {
  if (res.stage === 'end') {
    console.log('Status code: ' + res.status);
  }
};

page.open('http://some.url/that/does-not-exist', function() {
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Granted, this assumes that the server is going to actually return you a 404 (as opposed to a 200 masquerading as a 404, for example) -- but something along these lines should give you what you want.

Comment: An addendum: when I say "every resource received", I am also making the assumption that you're loading only one page per PhantomJS process. I've observed an interesting quirk wherein PhantomJS does not report requests for resources that it retrieves from its cache. (i.e., if you have a PhantomJS process that loads a page, and then another from the same site, it will only report a single static asset (e.g., jquery.js) on the first page where that asset is encountered.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that PhantomJS supports returning HTTP response codes currently. For this to be possible, the [WebPage](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/webpage.cpp) object would need to expose the QNetworkReply object and get its HTTP response code.

The HTTP response code can be obtained like this in the C++ code:

```
int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
```

Until this is integrated into PhantomJS' source, I think you'll just need to test on 'success' or 'failed'. If you really need to see the HTTP response code, you can run a CURL script to check the response from the server. I suspect that 'success' or 'failed' will be fine for your purposes though.

Answer (score 0):

complementing @founddrama answer, if you you have an styled 404 page and load some assets, onResourceReceived will show the status of all those assets, so i would recommend to change your code to something like

```
var definedStatus = false;
page.onResourceReceived = function(res) {
    if (res.stage === 'end' && definedStatus === false) {
        definedStatus = res.status;
    }
};

page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status == 'success' && definedStatus == 200) {    
        // do something
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        console.log("Erro")
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
});
```

so you will have status only of the page you requested